# How could I distinguish two types of protocol when channel is activated?

Tags: netty

I am using 4.0.4 version.There're two types of protocol in my project. One is message, another is command.

I successfully distinguish them by referring `portunification` example. But I found that the distinguish logic is coded within `decode` method. Which means I could only identify them by sending a message first. Bellowed is the codes:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in,
        List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    if (in.readableBytes() < 4) {
        return;
    }
    int identifier = in.getUnsignedByte(in.readerIndex());
    if(identifier == 'C') {
        switchToCommand(ctx);
    } else {
        switchToMessage(ctx);
    }
}
private void switchToCommand(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ctx.pipeline();
        p.addLast(new CommandHandler());
        p.remove(this);
}

private void switchToMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ctx.pipeline();
        p.addLast(new MessageHandler());

}
```

Worse is it could not trigger the `channelActive` event within my `CommandHandler` and `MessageHandler`. I think `channelRegistered` does not work either.

Is there any way to distinguish them when the channel is activated? Or how should I do for my scenario? Because I want to do something in `channelActive`, such as send a welcome message or add the channel to group.
Thanks!

Comment: You want to determine the kind of protocol without examining the data? That would be guessing, or magic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect the protocol without read some data first... How would the work ?

What you should use to notify other handlers in the ChannelPipeline about the detected protocol is to use ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(..) and pass in your own event. The handlers then can override userEventTriggered(..) and handle it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But UserEvent maybe much difficult for me. I prefer to follow netty supplied event handling.